# Android Studio safely move project folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a project using Android Studio and it works fine. Now I need to move the entire project somewhere else so I tried to copy paste the project folder to another location (from /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ to /home/username/Desktop/somefolder/AndroidProjects/ on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine) and the project stoped working. It shows a bunch of errors when I try to run the project from "/home/username/Desktop/somefolder/AndroidProjects/projectFolder " but it works fine when I run it from "/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/projectFolder "

The errors are related to a native module in my project and appear because AS tries to compile some files that SHOULD NOT BE COMPILED but in the build.gradle file I have excluded those file from sources that's why the project in "/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/projectFolder " works.

I haven't modified any of the source files or gradle files so the code and the gradle files are irelevant to the problem but I'll post them if you need to check them.

How can I move the Android Project around my computer without having to worry about this issues?

Comment: It would be useful to see what those errors actually say than your brief description of them

Comment: Have you searched the project sources for "/AndroidStudioProjects/" ? Are there any absolute paths in one of you build-files that should be relative?

Comment: Yes i have searched for absolute paths and I don't have any. Also I never use them that's why I did't specified that I searched for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with the files in .idea folder. I have created a new project and copied the files of the old project over but without the .idea folder.